# C program int to ascii conversion in certain range

Tags: c

A given question asks to write a C program "**snippet**" that converts a whole positive integer in the range from 0 to 10 000 stored as **int dnum** to the appropriate number of ASCII characters in an array of 5 characters. "Unused characters should NULL (ASCII 0). Note that "9" = ASCII 57(10) = 39 (H). The character array is **BCDchar**.

I started writing the snippet, but not sure how to continue. Thank you in advance. (**The question given is really confusing, that's why I don't quite understand what it really wants.**)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

int range = 0;
int dnum = 0;
char BCDchar[5]; //ASCII

if(range >= 0 && range <= 10000) {


   }
}
```

Comment: I don't get how you want to do the conversion. How should your int map to the characters?

Comment: You mean you want to convert an integer to a string representation? There are standard library functions for that!

Answer (score 0):

ASCII stands for American Standard Code for Information Interchange and is a character encoding standard. Each character has a code in the ASCII table and the question asks you to convert a given int to its ASCII representation.
Check [this](http://www.asciitable.com/) table and look for number 9: its decimal code is 57 which stands for 39 in Hex and that is what the hint is trying to tell you.
The result should be stored in `BCDchar` with a maximum length of 5 because the highest number that you can treat in this example would be 10000 which stands for 49 48 48 48 48 in ASCII format, you can use [this](http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/ascii/) to verify your solution.

Finally, if a conversion needs only 4 bytes you just put 0 for the last byte in `BCDchar`.

This is only trying to help you understand the question, implementing this in C should be fairly easy.

Answer (score 0):

What i think you need is the number xxxx to convert to a string "xxxx\0"
Store the digits of the number in an array.

```
int arr[5];
int n=dnum;    //assuming dnum is the number you want to convert
int i,no_of_digits;
for (i=0; i<5; i++){
    arr[i]=n%10;
    n=n/10;
    if(num==0){
        no_of_digits=i+1;
}
//now convert each digit to the respective ascii value
char *str=(char*) malloc((no_of_digits+1)*sizeof(char));
str[no_of_digits]='\0';
for (i=0; i<no_of_digits; i++){
    str[no_of_digits-i+1]=(char) arr[i]+48;
}
//str is the required string
```